# Eclipse keeps track of duplicate project

Tags: eclipse, project, cvs

I want to make copy of an existing eclipse project A and customize it and check it in CVS as a second project B. So I manually copied the entire project A directory into another workspace and opened the project in eclipse. Made changes (removed bunch of files), now when I try to check it in CVS, it somehow recognize it as project A and not a new project B. Seems like I copied some file that tracks the root. How can I remove it so I can check in as project B in CVS?

Even if I try to import the projectB in a different workspace in eclipse, I get the message, `project already exists`and identifies it as projectA.

Comment: Did your manual copying include copying the CVS directory inside it?

Comment: @nitind - Yes should I delete the CVS folder?

Comment: See if you can unshare the project through the UI first.

Comment: That did the trick. Removed the cvs folder, now I can commit. Thanks!

Comment: @nitind - if you reply it as answer I will pick your answer so you get credit for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if you can unshare the project through the UI. You likely have the original CVS directories that point back to the existing location.